# How to set URL for axios?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am creating a request from client with nuxtjs to laravel server. but the url request sent is http://localhost:3000/undefined/api/auth/signin instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/signin. I know this is simple question but I can't figure out how it works with nuxt and laravel

.env file
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000/
CLIENT_URL=http://localhost:3000/

```
import axios from 'axios'
const API_URL = process.env.APP_URL +'/api/'

...

  axiosPost(urlSuffix, data) {
    return axios.post(API_URL + urlSuffix, data, {
      useCredentials: true,
      headers: authHeader()
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.data
    })
...
```

Comment: can you use `const API_URL = {{ env('APP_URL')  }} +'/api/'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `laravel-mix`, (React, Vue or even Vanilla JS file which compiled by mix):

In your Javascript file:

```
import axios from 'axios'
const API_URL = process.env.MIX_APP_URL +'/api/'

// rest of your code...
```

Add this in your `.env` file:

```
MIX_APP_URL="${APP_URL}"
```

And re-compile your scripts by `npm run prod`, or `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`. Whichever you need.

If you are using in `blade` file, `process.env` isn't accessible there. Instead, add this:

```
const API_URL = {{url('/')}} +'/api/'
```

If you are using standalone nuxt.js:
Add in `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
    appUrl: process.env.APP_URL,
  }
}
```

And in your js file:

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.appUrl
});

// rest of your code
```

Comment: Exhaustive answer, thanks! Can you try to explain the 'undefined' part - I can't wrap my head around it..

Comment: Which stack do you use Laravel Mix or Nuxt.js?

Comment: I'm not the OP, just a curious bystander 

Comment: Okay, in `laravel-mix` you have to add prefix `MIX_` to available environment variable to js file. 

In next.js, you have to configure it in your `nuxt.config.js` file.